# If selecteditem not null textbox becomes visible

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app in C# with XAML.
I have various comboboxes and textboxes.
I would like to create an event with the following: When a combobox item is selected from combo1, textbox becomes visible.

I know the combobox property is Visibility:Visble/collapsed
not sure how to incorporate this into my event as i can't get the 
textbox.visibility property to work

```
private void ComboboxItem_Chosen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (combobox.SelectedText != null)
        {
            txttnumber.Visibility ??
        }
        else
        {
            combobox.Visibility ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Visibility`  under `System.Windows` will allows you to change the visibility of the object. You can set It

> **Visible**    : Display the element.
>
> **Hidden**     : Do not display the element, but reserve space for the
>   element in layout.
>
> **Collapsed**  : Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for
>   it in layout. Elements that have a Visibility value of Collapsed do
>   not occupy any layout space. By default, elements are Visible.

So In your case you should use like the following:

```
private void ComboboxItem_Chosen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (combobox.SelectedText != null)
    {
        txttnumber.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        combobox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Could get it done like this

```
private void ComboboxItem_Chosen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 { 
if (combobox.SelectedText != null)
 { txttnumber.Visibility =Visibility.Visible;
 } 
else 
{ combobox.Visibility =Visibility.Collapsed; 
}
 }
```